# Overriding a Dotnet Treeview Shortcuts/Hotkeys

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, shortcut

I'm actually working on a .Net Treeview-based Interface in 3D Studio Max, therefore coding with maxscript and C#. I've been desperately looking for a way to override the default behavior of a keyboard action, namely selecting the next node starting by the character type in.

For instance, I'd like to call a custom function when pressing the letter "F" and nothing more. By now, it actually run the function but also selects the next node starting with an F. Would anyone know how to prevent this last behavior ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `Handled`-Property (see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled.aspx)) or the `SuppressKeyPress`-Property (see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress.aspx)) of the KeyEventArgs to `true`?